# Javascript - Click multiple elements with class or id when clicking a different button

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, click, settimeout

I want to click one button that clicks other buttons at the same time or with a delay between each one. These additional buttons share the same class and their id's start with the same nomenclature. I know I can accomplish this easily with jQuery, but I want to make it work with Vanilla Javascript.

I tried using the querySelector, but this only triggers the first element.
Also, I found another solution that sets a Timeout for each button, the problem is that this gets triggered when the window loads and I need it to work when I click the other button.

This is my html code:

```html
<div>
  <button class="bundle-product-button" id="button1" onClick="alert('click button1');">Button 1</button>
  <button class="bundle-product-button" id="button2" onClick="alert('click button2');">Button 2</button>
  <button class="bundle-product-button" id="button3" onClick="alert('click button3');">Button 3</button>
</div>
<button class="add-bundle-to-cart">Trigger</button>
```

This only triggers the first button:

```
function testOne() {
    document.querySelector(".bundle-product-button").click();
}
document.querySelector(".add-bundle-to-cart").onclick = testOne;
```

And this triggers when the window loads:

```
var clickcallback = function(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let id = "button" + i;
    document.getElementById(id).click();
  }, 1000); // one second
  if(i <= 3) {
    clickcallback(i+1);
  }
};
clickcallback(1);
```

I know this might be simple but how can I trigger multiple clicks when clicking one element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelector` only match the first element, you have to use `querySelectorAll` and then for each

```
function testOne() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".bundle-product-button").forEach(function(el) {
       el.click();
    });
}
document.querySelector(".add-bundle-to-cart").onclick = testOne;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was close, I was testing with the "querySelectorAll", but I was missing the "el" element.